# Equations modelling a snowboarder/skier on a jump

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I am currently a highschool student elaborating an internal assessment for my mathematics AA HL course (a sort of research paper we must elaborate for the IB) and was looking into the relationship between mathematics and snowboarding. My current idea for research was investigating the feasibility of a quintuple cork given some initial conditions of the jump (angle, length, height, slope angle, etc.) and the rider (height, mass, etc.).

However, I've encountered some difficulties in finding appropriate differential equations to model a snowboarder's motion during a jump. Most existing models are either too complex, relying on matrix methods and other mathematics that are beyond my current level of math, or too simplistic, relying on basic kinematic equations that wouldn't allow for a meaningful investigation.

I would greatly appreciate your help in finding or developing differential equations that can accurately model a snowboarder's motion during a jump. I believe that with the right equations, I can utilize various numerical methods such as Euler and Runge-Kutta to analyze the feasibility of a quintuple cork on a specific jump. Whether you can suggest equations, recommend textbooks or research papers, or provide insights into the application of calculus and differential equations in this context, I would greatly appreciate your input.

**Let me make it clear I do not want my work done for me, since it would be against guidelines, rather some pointers to help me get started**

Comment: You might want to ask the question in physics SE for modelisation and differential equations. We might be more able to help you here with Runge-Kutta and stuff rather. 
Seems like an interesting project !

Comment: Can you confirm this is what you are trying to modelize https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlHIDO6wGrw  ?

Comment: @zwim Yes, that is similar to what I want to model, just that with more rotations and inversions ("the head going under the toes")